# Azure SQL Column encryption and backups

Tags: azure-sql-database, encryption

I am starting a project and for this project I need to encrypt columns containing PII Data in an Azure SQL database. As a developer, I have often handled this step in my code, but moving forward I wish to make this process more secure and use column level encryption on the SQL Azure database utilizing the DECRYPTBYKEY method.

My question here is, because the Certificate and the Master Key would be stored on the server and not the database (as I understand it) what happens when we need to take / restore a backup, or pull a backpac file from the export functionality? I assume that Azure's internal Db backups handle this seamlessly but they are only helpful for restoring to the same server.

Or is this all a bad idea and I should stick to encryption in my code?? That is obviously easy, but it feels like the wrong answer to me.

TIA

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but have you looked into [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)? With Always Encrypted, the encryption (and decryption) is handled by the drivers client-side. This saves you from doing it yourself, and keeps the keys client-side, so that data is encrypted in flight & on the server. There are some trade offs, but I'd suggest that over rolling your own encryption in your app code.

Comment: I did briefly. It seemed like it was more geared toward tools like the SQL Management Studio and not necessarily toward say an ASP.NET Website. But I admit I could have been wrong in that interpretation. Its a bit confusing. I will probably give it another read through tonight